# How to place a form to create a new entry on the main page. RoR

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I install Ubuntu, RoR and all RoR components. **Then I update question.** 
I need to get the form as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9bVR.png). I need this [part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiJ1T.png). So that it appears after clicking the `Add` button. I understand the logic of adding a form after clicking a button, but I can’t understand how the code of the form itself should look. Even a form with only `text_field` launches a site with an error 500. I may not know a lot, I'm just learning RoR.

index.html.erb

```
<style type="text/css">
    p{
        font-family: Times New Roman
        }
</style>
<p>
<strong><h1><%= @title %></h1>
<br><br><br>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase"><%= project.title %></h2>
    <ul>
    <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
        <% if todo.project_id == project.id %>
            <li><%= todo.text %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
<h2>Новая задача</h2>
<%= form_with(model: @todo, local: true) do |todo| %>
    <%= todo.text_field :text %>
    <%= todo.select (:project_id, option_for_select(project_array)) %>
    <%= todo.submit "Отмена"%>
    <%= todo.submit "ОК" %>
<% end %>
</strong>
</p>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

todos_controller.rb

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /todos
  # GET /todos.json
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end

  # GET /todos/1
  # GET /todos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /todos/new
  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  # GET /todos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /todos
  # POST /todos.json
  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.update(todo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todos/1
  # DELETE /todos/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todos_url, notice: 'Todo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo
      @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :isCompleted, :project_id)
    end
end
```

todoshnik_controller.rb

```
class TodoshnikController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @title = 'Задачи'
        @projects = Project.all
        @todos = Todo.all
        @todo = Todo.new
        @project_array = @projects.map { |project| [project.title, project.id] }
    end

    def create

    end

    def update

    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'todoshnik#index'
  resources :todos
  resources :projects
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `@todo` instance variable in the index action

```
def index
 @title = 'Задачи'
 @projects = Project.all
 @todos = Todo.all
 @todo = Todo.new
 @project_array = @projects.map { |project| [project.title, project.id] } #minimize the use of logic in your views. 
end
```

Add the form in your view.

```
<%= form_for @todo do |todo| %>
 <%= todo.text_field :text %>
 <%= todo.select :project_id, options_for_select(@project_array) %>
 <%= todo.submit "Отмена" %>
 <%= todo.submit "ОК" %>
<% end %>
```

If you have a TodoController with create and update action

```
<%= form_with(model: @todo, local: true) do |todo| %>
 <%= todo.text_field :text %>
 <%= todo.select :project_id, options_for_select(@project_array) %>
 <%= todo.submit "ОК" %>
<% end %>
```

This will always point to the create action of the TodoController

Comment: It did not help, error 500 again. I added the code for two more controllers that I have.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. `We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)`

Comment: from log  `(1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by TodoshnikController#index as HTML
  Project Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
  ↳ app/controllers/todoshnik_controller.rb:7:in 'map'
  Rendering todoshnik/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered todoshnik/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 19.4ms | Allocations: 3803)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 8.4ms | Allocations: 14372)`

Comment: @allenbrkn is, it’s right answer, but with 2 syntax mistakes. I tried edit answer, but author didn’t approve them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `@todo` is not referenced in your `index_controller.rb`, so your `index_controller.rb` `#index` action must be:

```
def index
  @title = 'Задачи'
  @projects = Project.all
  @todos = Todo.all
  @todo = Todo.new
end
```

Then in your `index.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @todo do |todo| %>
  <%= todo.text_field :text %>
  <%= project_array = @projects.map { |project| [project.title, project.id] } %>
  <%= todo.select (:project_id, option_for_select(project_array)) %>
  <%= todo.submit "Отмена" %>
  <%= todo.submit "ОК" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It did not help, error 500 again. I added the code for two more controllers that I have.

Answer (score -1):

try to install `simple_form_for` gem. It will allow you makes form without any troubles.

Comment: `$gem install simple_form_for`
`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'simple_form_for' (>= 0) in any repository`
`ERROR:  Possible alternatives: simple_form, simple_form-dojo,` `simple_form_ext,simple_format, simple-orm`
`$gem install simple_form`
`ERROR:  Error installing simple_form:`
`zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.`
i have this probles with bundle, and unknow how it's fix
`$bundle install`
`Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.5`

Comment: I used to have Ruby 2.3.3 installed, but I completely removed it from my computer and removed it from the PATH variable

Comment: gem 'simple_form' .  Add it to your gem file and run bundle install. And update your ruby version to newest. For update ruby version you should have rvm

Comment: Browse the gemfile, it says version 2.6.5. I use windows

Comment: If you have rvm try `rvm use 2.6.5` And repeat bundle install

Comment: As far as I know, rvm is only for linux or Mac, not for windows. Therefore, I do not have rvm.

Comment: Rails framework must be installed on Linux. But try to reinstall ruby with rvm